# How to spread data with one action to many stores in React flux arcitecture?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flux

How to some actions data to many stores?

For example, I got some post data from server in user action.

So this is simple psudo action code.

```
class UserActions {
    getPosts() {
        asyncFetch(apiEndPoint, function(data) {
            /*
             * data : {
             *    PostStore : [ ... ],
             *    UserStore : { ... },
             *    CommentStore : [ ... ],
             *    AppDataStore : { ... },
             *    StatusDataStore : { ... },
             *    ...
             * }
             *
             */

             PostActions.receiveStoreData(data.PostStore);
             UserActions.receiveStoreData(data.UserStore);
             CommentActions.receiveStoreData(data.CommentStore);
             AppDataActions.receiveStoreData(data.AppDataStore);
             StatusActions.receiveStoreData(data.StatusDataStore);
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm curious about setting many store data into the each stores calling actions in the action.

How to fix it with best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action creator should use the dispatcher to dispatch the corresponding action as below:

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';

class UserActions {
    getPosts() {
        asyncFetch(apiEndPoint, function(data) {
            const action = {
                type: 'ADD_POSTS',
                data
            };

            Dispatcher.dispatch(action);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then one or more store can register to the dispatcher and listen to the same `ADD_POSTS` action:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

let posts = [];

const PostStore = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    dispatcherIndex: AppDispatcher.register(action => {
        const { type, data } = action;

        switch (type) {
            case 'ADD_POSTS':
                posts = posts.concat(data);
                PostStore.emitChange();
            break;
            // ...
        }

        return true;
    });

    emitChange() {
        this.emit('change');
    }

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I know basic flux arcitecture. I just want to know that is this best way calling actions in action and to spreading to other stores.. Any way, thank you very much!

Comment: A best practice would be to dispatch a single action from an action creator, and that's usually applicable for REST payloads. In your case it looks like you're doing something different, as such it won't matter if you dispatch multiple actions from a single one, because it won't make the code as much confusing, especially if the behavior is consistent across the codebase.

Comment: +1. It sounds like you have store specific Actions ("receive store data"), but this answer demonstrates data specific Actions ("add posts") that multiple Stores might care about. Also a practice (maybe best?) would be to have a single Store responsible for the data (ex `PostStore`) and the other Stores query the `PostStore` to build on it. You can use `Flux.Dispatcher.waitFor()` to ensure `PostStore` updates itself before the others, for example.